# How to make buttons overflow to right side and scrollable

Tags: html, css, forms, button

[image]

I have this right now. I want the buttons to not wrap the div window.
Here is my div now:

```
#floatingRectangle {
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: black;
    padding: 8px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

<div id="floatingRectangle">
<form action="edit.php" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="pageSubmit" value="Prev">
<input type="submit" name="pageSubmit" value="Next">
.. etc
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this css to the code:-

```
#floatingRectangle form{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

This should Work

Comment: not working. still buttons remain wrapped

Comment: I have editted the code. Check it now. Wrongfully, I used class selector instead of id selector. It should work now

Comment: Hello, @GeneCode did it solve your problem? If it did, I'd really appreciate if you accept the answer. It works in the codepen here: https://codepen.io/rejownahmed/pen/WNJyxod

Comment: unfortunately I have changed design. But yeah I will accept your answer as proven it works in codepen

Answer (score 1):

It would be easy if you give parent component `display: flex` and the child component `justify-content: flex-end` css style

Comment: not working. still buttons remain wrapped